# How to implement player state machine

Tags: 2d, state-machine, godot, gdscript

I am very new to godot, and making 2d action platformer. I am trying to implement player state machine by following **Finite State Machine in Godot by Nathan Lovato** from GDQuest. However I am not sure how exactly I should write my code. I would really appreciate if someone could teach me how implement player state machine.

**Current Player script**. Player can move right and left, jump, and double jump.

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const UP_DIRECTION := Vector2.UP

export var can_move = true

export var speed := 200.0
export var jump_strength := 450
export var maximum_jumps := 2
export var double_jump_strength := 400
export var gravity := 1200

var _jumps_made := 0
var _velocity := Vector2.ZERO


onready var position2D = $Position2D
onready var _animation_player: AnimationPlayer = $Position2D/PlayerSkinIK/AnimationPlayer



func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:

    #Left and Right Movement Direction
    var _horizontal_direction = (
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right")
        - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    )

    #X and Y velocity
    _velocity.x = _horizontal_direction * speed
    _velocity.y += gravity * delta

    #Player State
    var is_falling := _velocity.y > 0.0 and not is_on_floor()
    var is_jumping := Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor()
    var is_double_jumping := Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") and is_falling
    var is_jump_cancelled := Input.is_action_just_released("jump") and _velocity.y < 0.0
    var is_idling := is_on_floor() and is_zero_approx(_velocity.x)
    var is_running := is_on_floor() and not is_zero_approx(_velocity.x)


    #Jump Counter
    if is_jumping:
        _jumps_made += 1
        _velocity.y = -jump_strength
    elif is_double_jumping:
        _jumps_made += 1
        if _jumps_made <= maximum_jumps:
            _velocity.y = -double_jump_strength
    elif is_jump_cancelled:
        _velocity.y = 0.0
    elif is_idling or is_running:
        _jumps_made = 0

    if (can_move == true):
        #Velocity Calculation
        _velocity = move_and_slide(_velocity, UP_DIRECTION)     

    #Flip Sprite 
    if get_global_mouse_position().x > $Position2D/PlayerSkinIK.global_position.x:

        position2D.scale.x=1
    else:

        position2D.scale.x=-1

    #Play WalkForward animation when moving towards mouse, play WalkBackward animation when moving away from mouse
    if position2D.scale.x==1:

        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
            print("forward1")
            if is_on_floor():
                _animation_player.play("Player-Run IK")
        elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
            print("backward1")
            if is_on_floor():
                _animation_player.play("Player-Run IK Backward")

    elif position2D.scale.x==-1:

        if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):    
            print("forward2")           
            if is_on_floor():
                _animation_player.play("Player-Run IK")
        elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
            print("backward2")
            if is_on_floor():
                _animation_player.play("Player-Run IK")

    #Animation Control
    if is_jumping or is_double_jumping:
        _animation_player.play("Player-Jump IK")
    elif is_falling:
        _animation_player.play("Player-Fall IK")
    elif is_idling:
        _animation_player.play("Player-Idle IK")
```

**Player Script:**

```
extends KinematicBody2D

class_name Player

enum States {ON_GROUND, IN_AIR, GLIDING}

var _state : int = States.ON_GROUND


export var speed := 200.0

var _velocity := Vector2.ZERO

var glide_gravity := 1000.0
var base_gravity := 4000.0
var glide_acceleration := 1000.0
var glide_max_speed := 1000.0
var glide_jump_impulse := 500.0
var jump_impulse := 1200.0


func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    
    var input_direction_x: float = (
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right")
        - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    )
    
    var is_jumping: bool = _state == States.ON_GROUND and Input.is_action_pressed("jump")
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("glide") and _state == States.IN_AIR:
        _state = States.GLIDING

    # Canceling gliding.
    if _state == States.GLIDING and Input.is_action_just_pressed("move_up"):
        _state = States.IN_AIR

    # Calculating horizontal velocity.
    if _state == States.GLIDING:
        _velocity.x += input_direction_x * glide_acceleration * delta
        _velocity.x = min(_velocity.x, glide_max_speed)
    else:
        _velocity.x = input_direction_x * speed

    # Calculating vertical velocity.
    var gravity := glide_gravity if _state == States.GLIDING else base_gravity
    _velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if is_jumping:
        var impulse = glide_jump_impulse if _state == States.GLIDING else jump_impulse
        _velocity.y = -jump_impulse
        _state = States.IN_AIR

    # Moving the character.
    _velocity = move_and_slide(_velocity, Vector2.UP)

    # If we're gliding and we collide with something, we turn gliding off and the character falls.
    if _state == States.GLIDING and get_slide_count() > 0:
        _state = States.IN_AIR
    
    
    
    if is_on_floor():
        _state = States.ON_GROUND

    
func change_state(new_state: int) -> void:
    var previous_state := _state
    _state = new_state
```

**Player Idle:**

```
extends PlayerState

func enter(_msg := {}) -> void:
    player.velocity = Vector2.ZERO

func physics_update(_delta: float) -> void:
    if not player.is_on_floor():
        state_machine.transition_to("Air")
        return
        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        state_machine.transition_to("Air", {do_jump = true})
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("move_left") or Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        state_machine.transition_to("Move")
```

**Player Move:**

```
extends PlayerState

func physics_update(delta: float) -> void:
    
    if not player.is_on_floor():
        state_machine.transition_to("Air")
        return
    
    var input_direction_x: float =(
        Input.get_action_strength("move_right")
        - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    )
    
    player.velocity.x = player.speed * input_direction_x
    player.velocity.y += player.graivty * delta
    player.velocity = player.move_and_slide(player.velocity, Vector2.UP)        
    
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump"):
        state_machine.transition_to("Air", {do_jump = true})
    elif is_equal_approx(input_direction_x, 0.0):
        state_machine.transition_to("Idle")
```

**Player State:**

```
extends State

class_name PlayerState

var player: Player

func _ready() -> void:
    
    yield(owner, "ready")
    
    player = owner as Player
    
    assert(player != null)
```

**State:**

```
# Virtual base class for all states.
class_name State
extends Node

# Reference to the state machine, to call its `transition_to()` method directly.
# That's one unorthodox detail of our state implementation, as it adds a dependency between the
# state and the state machine objects, but we found it to be most efficient for our needs.
# The state machine node will set it.
var state_machine = null


# Virtual function. Receives events from the `_unhandled_input()` callback.
func handle_input(_event: InputEvent) -> void:
    pass


# Virtual function. Corresponds to the `_process()` callback.
func update(_delta: float) -> void:
    pass


# Virtual function. Corresponds to the `_physics_process()` callback.
func physics_update(_delta: float) -> void:
    pass


# Virtual function. Called by the state machine upon changing the active state. The `msg` parameter
# is a dictionary with arbitrary data the state can use to initialize itself.
func enter(_msg := {}) -> void:
    pass


# Virtual function. Called by the state machine before changing the active state. Use this function
# to clean up the state.
func exit() -> void:
    pass
```

**State Machine:**

```
# Generic state machine. Initializes states and delegates engine callbacks
# (_physics_process, _unhandled_input) to the active state.
class_name StateMachine
extends Node

# Emitted when transitioning to a new state.
signal transitioned(state_name)

# Path to the initial active state. We export it to be able to pick the initial state in the inspector.
export var initial_state := NodePath()

# The current active state. At the start of the game, we get the `initial_state`.
onready var state: State = get_node(initial_state)


func _ready() -> void:
    yield(owner, "ready")
    # The state machine assigns itself to the State objects' state_machine property.
    for child in get_children():
        child.state_machine = self
    state.enter()


# The state machine subscribes to node callbacks and delegates them to the state objects.
func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    state.handle_input(event)


func _process(delta: float) -> void:
    state.update(delta)


func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    state.physics_update(delta)


# This function calls the current state's exit() function, then changes the active state,
# and calls its enter function.
# It optionally takes a `msg` dictionary to pass to the next state's enter() function.
func transition_to(target_state_name: String, msg: Dictionary = {}) -> void:
    # Safety check, you could use an assert() here to report an error if the state name is incorrect.
    # We don't use an assert here to help with code reuse. If you reuse a state in different state machines
    # but you don't want them all, they won't be able to transition to states that aren't in the scene tree.
    if not has_node(target_state_name):
        return

    state.exit()
    state = get_node(target_state_name)
    state.enter(msg)
    emit_signal("transitioned", state.name)
```

Comment: The https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/design-patterns/finite-state-machine/ you mentioned seems tto use a player with walking and jumping as an example already. So it would achieve anything your character should do minus double jump. 
So what exactly is the problem you encountered while following this tutorial?

Comment: One of the problem that I encountered is that PlayerState cannot reference Player node.  "The Identifier "Player" isnt a valid type (not a script or class), or couldnt be found on base "self"

`class_name PlayerState
extends State

# Typed reference to the player node.
var player: Player


func _ready() -> void:


 yield(owner, "ready")
 
 
 player = owner as Player


 assert(player != null)
`

Comment: If you want to reference your Player class you have to first give it a name in code by writing 
class_name Player
at the top of the class. Otherwise no other script knows what a player is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After reloading the scene, the script successfully referenced the player. However, another problem started popping up, that is "the identifier "player" isnt declared in the current scope." Although, I have PlayerState and referenced var player: Player, the "player" in the PlayerIdle and PlayerMove script cannot reference it.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you maybe edit your question to include your current state at the moment? Without you code I have to blind guess mostly. Did you make sure, that the PlayerIdle/PlayerMove scripts extend from PlayerState?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. After reloading the scene, the script successfully referenced the player. One another issue is that "input_direction_x" isn't declared in the player script. Do i have to write "func input_direction_x" in the player script as well, though I have it on the PlayerMove script.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time I start like this.
I hope you will find it helpful.

```
enum States {IDLE, MOVE, JUMP}  
var current_state = States.IDLE  

func _state_logic():  
    match current_state:
        States.IDLE:
            #  STATE TRANSITION: IDLE -- MOVE
            if Input.is_aciton_pressed("move_player"):
                current_state = State.MOVE

            #  STATE TRANSITION: IDLE -- JUMP
            if Input.is_aciton_pressed("move_player"):
                current_state = State.JUMP

        States.MOVE:
            movement_direction = input_direction

            #  STATE TRANSITION: IDLE -- JUMP
            if Input.is_aciton_pressed("move_player"):
                current_state = State.JUMP

            #  STATE TRANSITION: MOVE -- IDLE
            if Input.is_action_released("move_player"):
                current_state = State.IDLE


        States.JUMP:
            handle_player_jump()

            # OTHER STATE TRANSITION CODE
```